# Number of Contigious subarrays satisfying constraints

Tags: algorithm, number-theory

Given array A , find number of continious sub arrays which satisfies condition:

> There is no pair `(i,j)` in the subarray such that `i < j` and `A[i] mod A[j]= M`

`1<=A[i]<=100000`

> My Approach: Do it naive way in `O(n^2)` time complexity, which is bad.

Can I reduce it to `(nlogn)` ?

Comment: Can you describe your O(n^2) approach? it's pretty fast actually. And how large is `M` and `n` ?

Comment: Both M and n are upto 10^5.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we need to find all pairs such that `i < j` and `A[i] mod A[j] = M`

If `a mod b = m`, then `a mod d = m, where d is a divisor of b and d > m`

Hash the numbers in the array. For each number `a` in the array, check if `a - m` or any of the divisors of `a - m` are elements in the array and their index is greater than the index of `a` - enumerate any existing pairs `(a, a - m)` or `(a, divisor of (a - m) > m)` in `O(n sqrt n)`.

Clearly, any contiguous sub-arrays satisfying the condition lie between any such pairs. If we aggregate the pairs in an interval tree, as we traverse the array, we can test if we are within a pair in `O(log n)` time. Once we detect we are overlapping a pair (an interval in the tree), we reset our window to `(i + 1, j)` (where `(i,j)` is the interval) and keep counting; we add to the total the largest segments achievable according to the formula, `segment * (segment + 1) / 2`, subtracted by the previous overlapping count.

Answer (score 0):

This is a O(N) time complexity, but requires O(N+M) space complexity:

- We scan the array and perform A[i] = A[i] mod M
- Keep a counter array of size N which keeps track of how many elements before it respect the given condition (basically not being the equal to the current element):
- C[i] = the number of elements A[j], such that A[j]!=A[i] where j

Consider the array:

- Original A array: 12, 25, 16, 14, 37, 18, 28, 17, 9, 37
- New A array:      0,  1,  4,  2,  1,  6,  4,  5,  9, 1 (A[i] mod M)
- Counter array:    0,  1,  2,  3,  2,  3,  3,  4,  5, 4

The counter array can be constructed incrementally based on previous values:

- A[j] = A[i] and j

  Otherwise C[i] = C[i-1]+1;

When looking for the last occurrence of A[i] before index i, we need to keep a dictionary (A[i], last-index-of-A[i]) for fast lookup. 
Since we keep only values for A[i] mod M => a O(M) dictionary will do.

We now just sum up the counter array values:

```
Number of contiguous subarrays = Sum(C)
```

In this case we will have 27 contiguous subarrays that respect this condition.

Comment: What about the array `{9,5,4}` and `M=2` ? In this case, `(9 mod 2) == (5 mod 2)` but `(9 mod 5) ≠ 2`. Wouldn't your new array `{1,1,0}` mislead us to a wrong count?

Comment: Could you explain the first step of the algorithm? A[i] = A[i] mod M

Comment: @גלעדברקן indeed this is a wrong solution and I will think of a correct one.

Comment: Could you please give me some pseudo code, or some reference, for detailed study?